# How To Render Non-Stable Parent Attribute In React

Tags: reactjs, jsx

I am having issue to render a A `variable Parent Attribute` in React. For example

```
[
  {
    "IT2183": {
        "Location": "US",
        "Price": "$10",
        "Name": "Chairs",
    }
  },
  {
    "IT5846": {  // This Attribute is not Stable. It is Item ID which is different for every record.
        "Location": "US",
        "Price": "$20",
        "Name": "Note Book",
    }
  }
]

{data.map((Item) => (
  <div>
    {attribute.Location} //As Attribute name in the Array is not stable. How to call it. 
    {attribute.Price}
    {attribute.Name}
  </div>
))}
```

In the above example The Item Id which is a parent attribute and the other objects are nested inside it. For every record it is different which is basically the Item ID. I don't know how to call it.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values).

```
{data.map((Item) => (
  <div>
    {Object.values(Item)[0].Location}
    {Object.values(Item)[0].Price}
    {Object.values(Item)[0].Name}
  </div>
))}
```

Comment: Hi @William Wang . Thanks a lot for your answer and time. It is working for me.